# How to erase all transaction history of an account?

Tags: accounts, history

Is there a way to remove all the transaction history of an account? Let's say I have sold my account name, but don't want to show all the old transactions of that account.

Comment: Its possible to delete the contract data stored in ram, but not the transaction that were made .any one reply action basing on  transaction log .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the blockchain is immutable and distributed.

Due to immutability, any change in past blocks would alter the block hash, making the rest of the chain invalid.

Due to being distributed, anyone can download the blockchain, and it would be difficult to erase it from everyone's memory storage.

Comment: so if i sold my account name, that person will still have all the transaction history of that account too? even if the keys have changed?

Comment: yup that's right